# Spatial clustering gridded data with missing values (over water)

Tags: r, clustering

I'm trying to cluster a spatial dataset, and use the cluster labels as an input to a second process.  I've been using the `spdep` package in R.

I've got gridded data at .5 degree lat/lon resolution.  There are 19 covariates in the example subset of it [linked here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i72na4k0k5gqvvx/example_data?dl=0)

The following shows that I can't calculate the minimum spanning tree -- a necessary input into `skater` -- when the dataset includes areas undefined because they are over water.

How would one get around this?

```
system('wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/i72na4k0k5gqvvx/example_data?dl=0')
load('example_data')

    1> with(x, plot(lon,lat))
    1> library(spdep)
    1> bh.nb <- cell2nb(length(unique(x$lon)),length(unique(x$lat)),torus=F,type='queen')
    1> lcosts <- nbcosts(nb = bh.nb, data = x,method='euclidean')
    Error in data[id.neigh, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

The points are over the western US and Mexico:
[image]

If I restrict the data to cut out the missing values, I have no problem:

```
x = x[x$lon>-117,]
bh.nb <- cell2nb(length(unique(x$lon)),length(unique(x$lat)),torus=F,type='queen')
lcosts <- nbcosts(nb = bh.nb, data = x,method='euclidean')
nb.w <- nb2listw(bh.nb, lcosts, style="B")
mst.bh <- mstree(nb.w,10)
res1 <- skater(mst.bh[,1:2], x, 5)
plot(res1, cbind(x$lon,x$lat), cex.circles=0.035, cex.lab=.7)
```

and I get this:
[image]

How do I get around this?  I want to be able to cluster the land surfaces, including islands and peninsulas.  I suppose that I want islands to be linked to their nearest point of land... but the more I think about islands, the more I'm realizing that's a can of worms.

References as well as fixes to the specific problem with the `spdep` interface are sought.

Comment: Hi, have you found a way for clustering your data? I'm facing almost the same question. Thanks.